# Is there a Google Calendar API that returns Ids of recurrent events

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I have gone through the following link:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/instances#examples

My problem is that if I have to retrieve Events on a particular dates say: today and tomorrow.

Now if I have created this recurring event on day before yesterday to be repeating on a daily basis, it should show up. Microsoft has done it by providing calendar view, where all the events are retrieved on the days they fall on (whether recurrent or all day events).

Please let me know whether there is any API that returns the id of events that are recurrent during a range of dates, or month.

If I can have ID of recurrent events, I can know with the help of calculation. How can I use the API in the link above, if I don't have the IDs of the recurring events.

Comment: I haven't officialy tried this yet, but you can probably fetch the recurringEventId  after a successful call to [Events methods](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource) in Calendar API. recurringEventId is part of the [events resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations).

Comment: I have edited my question for specific goal I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Events events = mService.events().list("primary")
                    .setMaxResults(20)
                    .setTimeMin(now)
                    .setTimeMax(dateEndDay)
                    .setOrderBy("startTime")
                    .setSingleEvents(true)
                    .setShowDeleted(false)
                    .execute();
```